# How to know the address of my tomcat for mvn?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu machine in which the tomcat server is sitting in `/var/lib/tomcat6`, now I have a different directory for my code.

I do mvn tomcat6:run but whenever I say localhost from browser it takes the url of `/var/lib` directory, though my prompt is running for mvn.

I have also stopped the default tomcat using sudo service tomcat6 stop.

But now I want to access my mvn's tomcat from other directory and also want the choice to keep the `/var/lib/tomcat6` as is, wherever I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of Tomcat on your server, you need to run them on different ports (or interfaces). I don't know thich Tomcat Maven plugin you are using, but it probably have a configuration option something like:

```
<configuration>
    <port>/* Set a different port here */</port>
</configuration>
```

You should then be able to run both Tomcat instances and access them through different ports.